# Can you change the color of a Rect once it's drawn on canvas?

Tags: android

```
RectF rect1 = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

Is there anyway I can change the color of `rect1` by calling `rect1.setColor`, or
do I have to redraw in `Canvas` with a different paint?

Comment: You will have to redraw in other to change the color. Any changes in the graphics buffer you will need to call invalidate()

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate first and redraw the rectangle again with different color.

```
invalidate();
mCanvas.drawRect(rect, differentPaint);
```